# Describe your ability to solve this number sequence!

Tags: word, number-sequence, english

Here is a sequence of numbers:

#### 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, -, -, -, 10, 12

Can you fill in the three blanks and thus reveal your excellent puzzle-solving ability?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A basic solution is

> ACE (which excellent in the question clues)

as the sequence

> 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, A, C, E, 10, 12 are even numbers in hexadecimal.